# Having trouble with implementation

Tags: lightbox2

I have spent 2 hours + on the lightbox. I have checked paths to CSS and Javascript. I have used both the included jquery and Google's imported JQuery.

When I click an image it opens a new window with that image larger on a white background. I want it to overlay the current page with <> and x.

You can see an example: http://demopbdesignsource.tierstrategies.com/a.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code on your page I do not see where you are calling the lightbox.js script - that needs to be called right before the body close tag.

Also lightbox help states : If you already use jQuery on your page, make sure it is loaded before lightbox.js.  - ◦Include the Javascript at the bottom of your page before the closing /body tag:

I used the lightbox-plus-jquery.js and called that just before the close of the body tag and it worked. I called the lightbox-plus-jquery.js just before the close of the body tag because it has both jquery and lightbox combined.

I am still working on the page and I am just using html not .net but the lightbox would work the same. If you look at my source you will see the script call right before /body tag.
http://just-in.com/recycledDresser/index.htm

Hope this helps.

Debra W.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the Lightbox script.
Something like

Placing it in the line before the  line works for me.

Both
http://demopbdesignsource.tierstrategies.com/X/LightBox.css
and
http://demopbdesignsource.tierstrategies.com/X/LightBox.js
cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided in the question is giving 404 right now.
but I think you just need to follow the steps given at
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ 
to set up lightbox.
you may have missed either of the following :

Include the CSS at the top of your page in your `<head>` tag:

```
<link href="path/to/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Include the Javascript at the bottom of your page before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="path/to/lightbox.js"></script>
```